# Webscraping - html issue

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

Ive been trying this code and getting some success but cannot figure out the next step

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from termcolor import colored
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import lxml.html as lh

import pprint
import json



url2 = "https://www.procyclingstats.com/rankings.php"



print(colored('#Step1','green'))
response = requests.get(url2)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
table = soup.find('table', {'class':'basic'})
headers = [heading.text for heading in table.find_all('th',{"class":"cu600"})]
#print(headers)

#why do I only get two headers here (prev, team)?





response = requests.get(url2)
dfs = pd.read_html(response.text)[0]
#print(list(dfs))


#with pd.option_context('display.max_rows', None, 'display.max_columns', None):  # more options can be specified also
 #  print(dfs)
   
print(colored('#Step1','red'))


print(colored('#Step2','green'))

url3 = "https://www.procyclingstats.com/rider/tadej-pogacar"

response = requests.get(url3)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
table2 = soup.find({'class':'class="mt10 pps"'})
#headers = [heading.text for heading in table1.find_all('th',{"class":"cu600"})]
#print(headers)



# Usually the line below is enough
# But for some reason returning Forbidden
#dfs = pd.read_html(url)[0]

response = requests.get(url3)
dfs2 = pd.read_html(response.text)[0]


#with pd.option_context('display.max_rows', None, 'display.max_columns', None):  # more options can be specified also
    #print(dfs2)
 

child_soup = soup.find('h3')
    
for i in child_soup.children:
      print("child :  ", i)
    
print('\n'*3)
```

I end up with the child as Rider (result text below)

Ive been trying this code and getting some success but cannot figure out the next step

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from termcolor import colored
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import lxml.html as lh

import pprint
import json



url2 = "https://www.procyclingstats.com/rankings.php"



print(colored('#Step1','green'))
response = requests.get(url2)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
table = soup.find('table', {'class':'basic'})
headers = [heading.text for heading in table.find_all('th',{"class":"cu600"})]
#print(headers)

#why do I only get two headers here (prev, team)?





response = requests.get(url2)
dfs = pd.read_html(response.text)[0]
#print(list(dfs))


#with pd.option_context('display.max_rows', None, 'display.max_columns', None):  # more options can be specified also
 #  print(dfs)
   
print(colored('#Step1','red'))


print(colored('#Step2','green'))

url3 = "https://www.procyclingstats.com/rider/tadej-pogacar"

response = requests.get(url3)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
table2 = soup.find({'class':'class="mt10 pps"'})
#headers = [heading.text for heading in table1.find_all('th',{"class":"cu600"})]
#print(headers)



# Usually the line below is enough
# But for some reason returning Forbidden
#dfs = pd.read_html(url)[0]

response = requests.get(url3)
dfs2 = pd.read_html(response.text)[0]


#with pd.option_context('display.max_rows', None, 'display.max_columns', None):  # more options can be specified also
    #print(dfs2)
 

child_soup = soup.find('h3')
    
for i in child_soup.children:
      print("child :  ", i)
    
print('\n'*3)
```

I end up with the child as Rider (result text below)

```
#Step2
child :   Rider
```

What Im trying to capture is the 'points per speciality' and the values.

There is a second question as to why I only get two tags when they all appear to have the same name?

[Photo and arrow showing desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eDYcv.png)

Answer (score 0):

```py
import re

url2 = "https://www.procyclingstats.com/rankings.php"
response = requests.get(url2)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")
table = soup.find("table", {"class": "basic"})
thead = table.find("thead")
headers = [heading.text for heading in thead.find_all("th")]


url3 = "https://www.procyclingstats.com/rider/tadej-pogacar"

response = requests.get(url3)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")
ul = soup.find("ul", {"class": "basic"})
li = ul.find_all("li")
d = {}
for l in li:
    m = re.search("(\d+)(.*)", l.text)
    d[m.group(2)] = m.group(1)

print(headers)
print(d)

# ['#', 'Prev.', 'Diff.', 'Rider', 'Team', 'Points']
# {'One day races': '1641', 'GC': '3444', 'Time trial': '1147', 'Sprint': '302', 'Climber': '3816'}
```